# Google Image Search reverted to old style

Tags: google-image-search

A few days ago Google Image Search reverted back to the old style, I much prefer the new style. It does not matter if I'm logged in or not.

How do I tell Google I want the new style image search?

**Edit:**
This is the style I *don't* want.
[image: screenshot]

**Edit: 2**
It seems it's a combined google/firefox issue. If I start FF in safe-mode I get the desired flowing view.

Comment: Closing as the question is too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. Somehow the default search in my google tool bar had reverted back to `www.google.se` instead of `www.google.com` as I usually have.

Oddly enough if I enter this url `http://www.google.com/images?q=halloween` I get the layout I want but if I change `.com` to `.se` like this `http://www.google.se/images?q=halloween` I get the old style with only one page at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the end of the search results page and click the link called **“Switch to standard version”**.

[image]

Comment: No such link, see edit.

Comment: Strange. I can see it. The only difference between the basic and the standard version: There is `&sout=1` at the end of the address path of basic version. Look for this code in your address bar and remove it to view the standard version.

Comment: No such value-pair in the url. It seems it's a combined google/firefox issue. If I start FF in safe-mode I get the desired view.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the image search. Click [Switch to basic version](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web%20Search/thread?tid=091ab94083817852&hl=en)

Comment: As you can see on my screenshot I didn't/don't have that link **and** I want the new search not the basic version.

Comment: why down vote ?

Comment: My guess is that someone seen that your answer is a duplicate and got furious about it.